# Tkinter: checkbox list not responsive

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter, checkboxlist

I am trying to create a list of checkboxes with a loop. I have modified the implementation of someone else's code which uses the same concept and should have the same function as what I want. When I try to print the state of each checkbox, none of them are updated to 1. They all stay at 0 even if I click them.

Here is my code, the `test()` function doesn't behave as I expect it to.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog
import os

def browse():
    filez = tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory(parent=window, title='Choose a file')

    ent1.insert(20, filez)

    dirs = os.listdir(filez)

    # remove previous IntVars
    intvar_dict.clear()

    # remove previous Checkboxes
    for cb in checkbutton_list:
        cb.destroy()
    checkbutton_list.clear()
 
    for filename in dirs:
        # create IntVar for filename and keep in dictionary
        var = tkinter.IntVar()

        # create Checkbutton for filename and keep on list
        c = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, text=filename, variable=var)
        c.pack()
        intvar_dict[filename] = var
        checkbutton_list.append(c)

def test():
    for key, value in intvar_dict.items():
        if value.get() > 0:
            print("HIIIIII")
        print('selected:', key)
        #print (value.get())


# to keep all IntVars for all filenames
intvar_dict = {}
 # to keep all Checkbuttons for all filenames
checkbutton_list = []

window = tkinter.Tk()

lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="Path")
lbl.pack()

ent1 = tkinter.Entry(window)
ent1.pack()

btn1 = tkinter.Button(window, text="Select Path", command=browse)
btn1.pack()

btn1 = tkinter.Button(window, text="Test Checkboxes", command=test)
btn1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tried out your code. When I click "Test Checkboxes", it prints "HIIIIII" for each of the checkboxes I ticked, and doesn't print that for the checkboxes I didn't tick. Is that not what's happening for you?

Comment: You code works as expected on my end. I added a print statement to the loop to check the value of `value.get()` and the ones I have selected were changed to `1`.

Comment: If this is not happening on your end I do not think it is a problem with your code but rather a bug. What version of python/OS are you using?

Comment: Thank for taking at look at this guys. I guess I may be a bug, I'll look into it. It still does not work as expected for me. Im on Python 3.6

Comment: Are you running this code in an interpreter like the QtConsole? Because if I run your code directly, it works but it doesn't from the QtConsole. To make it work, I need to specify the master of the `IntVar` (`var = tkinter.IntVar(master=window)`).

Comment: Thank you j_4321 That works. I was using QtConsole. Can you explain why I have to specify the master? Is it something with QtConsole? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I think the QtConsole runs an extra tcl interpreter so it's like there are two active `Tk()` instances and if you don't specify the master, then Tk chooses the wrong one as default. As a consequence your `IntVar` doesn't belong to the same interpreter as your `Checkbutton` so they can't communicate.

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly if executed directly, however the issue described in the question happens if the code is run from the QtConsole. This problem can be fixed by specifying the master of the `IntVar`: `var = tkinter.IntVar(master=window)`.

Indeed, the QtConsole creates automatically a `Tk` instance, so when `window` is created, there are two `Tk` instances. Then, when the `IntVar` is created, tkinter links it to the first `Tk` instance, i.e. not the master of the `Checkbutton`. Since the `Checkbutton` and the `IntVar` do not belong to the same `Tk` instance (i.e. different Tcl interpreters), they cannot communicate. This is why the value of the variable doesn't correspond to the state of the checkbox.